# Mocking System.getenv other than with powermock

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

Considering question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980599/7203487. 
Only one method among methods in class contains System.getenv which needs to be mocked.  Problem is I require to take jacoco code coverage which I get as 0% due to use of powemock. Is there a way possible to mock  system and attain code coverage with or without powermock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look into the [System Rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules) for JUnit 4, especially the [EnvironmentVariables](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#EnvironmentVariables).

```
public class EnvironmentVariablesTest {

  @Rule
  public final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();

  @Test
  public void setEnvironmentVariable() {
    environmentVariables.set("name", "value");
    assertEquals("value", System.getenv("name"));
  }
}
```

Comment: super. i never knew this before!! thanks for sharing

Comment: @sahlouls please check https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/download.html

Comment: @t-d the main issue is the lib is instable, my builds fail often

Comment: I have a build with version 1.19.0 and it works. Can you attach the build logs with error?

Comment: Wait..the above is third party library? meaning your own custom library or inbuild in Junit?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Roland Weisleder.

EnvironmnetVariables is not part of junit . you need to add below dependency

https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/download.html

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
  <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: He already added link for system rules. And answer is already accepted.

Comment: Thanks @T D  .. I was thinking the Ronald code is inbuilt in junit.... I was looking for something in built in JUNIT.... Not everyone has luxury to add third party libraries..especially if you are  working for someone else